# SQL: Merge rows from complexed table

Tags: mysql, group-by

Let's assume there is a raw data table as below:

```
Date  |  ID |  Stats
9/12  |  A  |  10
9/13  |  A  |  20
9/13  |  B  |  5
9/14  |  B  |  3
9/15  |  A  |  100
9/16  |  A  |  200
9/17  |  A  |  250
```

I want to make a new table by SQL query as below from above:

```
Start_Date  |  End_Date  | ID |  Sum(Stats)
9/12        |  9/13      | A  |  30
9/13        |  9/14      | B  |  8
9/15        |  9/17      | A  |  550
```

In this case, how can I write SELECT query?

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY. As such, this problem is (perhaps) insoluble.

Comment: Wouldn't a combination of Date and ID form a compound key?

Comment: @ScottSellers Yes. It could. But it's not clear that it does - which was why I caveated my previous statement with the parenthetical remark.

Comment: As @ScottSellers says, combination of Date and ID can be a compound key. :)

Comment: But even if it is not a compund key you could do a subquery that forms a table with the sum of the stats grouped by the date and id.

Comment: * Each date must have < 2 employees (0, 1, 2)

Answer (score 1):

It is working in my tests:

```
select  
   alias1.DATA,
   alias1.DATA + interval 1 day , 
   alias2.ID, 
   sum(alias2.stats)
from 
   TEST as alias1 inner join 
   TEST as alias2 on (alias2.data >= alias1.data and alias2.data <= alias1.data + interval 1 day)

group by alias1.DATA,alias1.DATA + interval 1 day,alias2.ID
```

Comment: Please, note that I am assuming that you allways want this structure in each row: Date, Date+1 day, ID_a, sum(stats between Date and Date + 1 of ID_a )

Comment: Thanks for kind help. It almost works (!), but 9/15~9/17 data from TEST table do not work. :(

Comment: As I sad it will always have the DATE, DATE+1 structure.

Comment: I would use a procedure.